# ssh-keygen for remote access not working

Tags: linux, ssh, rsa, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to setup a connection with a remote server and since I don't want to insert the password every time I decided to create a public-private key pair and use it for authentication.

You can find the procedure I followed at these two sources:

- [How to forge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/mounting-remote-directories-with-sshfs-on-ubuntu-11.10)
- [The Geek stuff.com](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)

But something is not working, in particular after copying the key with:

`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myUserName@remoteHost`

the following file gets created on the remote server

`-rw------- 1 myUserName remoteHost 399 Jan 10 19:20 authorized_keys`

but even though its content matches the public key I have on the local server I am still prompted for a password when I try connecting with `ssh`.
I tried changing permissions on the `.ssh` folder on both ends but nothing seems to work.

I am pretty clueless, any idea?

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**

This is the output returned by using command `ssh -vvv myUserName@remoteHost`

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to .
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/matteorr/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host  from file "/home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 117/256
debug2: bits set: 518/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 10:96:6d:dd:95:fc:85:a7:1d:2e:a1:9e:6c:6f:76:62
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host from file "/home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host from file "/home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host  is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/matteorr/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fba8a5f92b0)
debug2: key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/matteorr/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: Can you run ssh login with the -vvv option for diagnostics? (The more 'v'-s the better.)

Comment: @mockinterface - thanks for the suggestion, check updates in question with the result of using diagnostic option.

Comment: can you show us the error appears on you?

Comment: From a brief look it looks like the server you are connecting to is using gssapi/kerberos and the authentication fails.

Comment: @mockinterface - but other users are able to connect remotely, does that mean it's a problem in my process?any suggestion?

Comment: so it is not " WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!  ", is it?

Comment: I am more baffled by "/tmp/krb5cc_1000" is not found and the unspecified gssapi failures. Do you have to run "kinit" on the client side to generate a kerberos ticket? Are you using up-to-date ssh?

Comment: @MortezaLSC - what are you referring to?

Comment: @mockinterface - 1) No clue. 2) Supposedly, I installed few weeks ago the whole OS

Comment: It looks to me that the host you are connecting to demands GSSAPI authentication (aka Kerberos for simplicity). So even though your public key is right, it's an extra security imposition that's placed by the server side. You should be in the kerberos domain to be able to login to that server, it's not just about ssh.

Comment: @Matteo I reckon it is better move this question (including the debug log) to http://serverfault.com

Comment: was it man in the middle friend? that says: (Add correct host key in /home/ramesh/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/ramesh/.ssh/known_hosts: 6
Permission denied (publickey,password).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication).

To summarize, the problem was about permissions: my home on the remote server had `777` permission and it turns out that `ssh` will complain unless you remove write permission to other users on your home folder.

`chmod 700` (or also `755`) of my home solved it for me.